# Get promise value outside of scope nodejs

Tags: node.js, nestjs

My script is

```
$scope.uid  = '';

 this.myService.getCount(response).then(function (value) {
           $scope.uid  = value;

        });
```

I want value outside of this promise but I am getting error Cannot find name '$scope'

Comment: did you declare `const $scope = {}`?

Comment: @ManuelSpigolon yes I have declared it

Answer (score 0):

Have you try to have uid  as a class member and if you shoud use outside your class scope you can define it as a static member.
If it is will not help you please provide more detailed information

```
class YourClass {
    static uid: string = '';

    static YourClassFunc() {
        this.myService.getCount(response).then(function (value) {
            YourClassFunc.uid  = value;
        });
    }
}

https://www.tutorialsteacher.com/typescript/typescript-static
```